# Hybris how to create another storefront with its own urls

Tags: ant, sap-commerce-cloud, storefront

I have created a new hybris project with its own b2c electronics storefront with its own mappings:

website.electronics.http=http://electronics.local:9001/teststorefront1
website.electronics.https=https://electronics.local:9002/teststorefront1

Now I want to create another storefront and attach it to this project (I want to share the database between the sites) with its own URLs and also I want a new initialdata extension for this storefront

How can I achieve this with ant commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server, you only have one DB configured.

If you want a new storefront, you have to create a new website in the backoffice or with Impex.

If you want a custom project associated (with the initialdata directory), you have to run an ant command

```
ant modulegen
```

And select the type of storefront you want (for example, b2caccelerator) and the name of the project (mystore)

Then you set your URL

```
website.mystore.http=http://mystore.local:9001/teststorefront1
website.mystore.https=https://mystore.local:9002/teststorefront1
```

In your website configuration, in the backoffice, you have to configure the URL Pattern to match the URL configured before.

Comment: The ant modulegen will generate the new XXXStorefront extension and XXXInitialdata extension?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to choose what you want to generate. If you choose the b2caccelerator, the storefront and initialdata will be generated.